# Let knitr/kable display latex code for further editing

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I have to put all my code from a Rmarkdown document into pure LaTeX format in Overleaf. For this reason, I can't use my knitr code anymore to produce latex tables right away, but I need to write the LaTeX code by myself.

I through, although kable/kableExtra do now show LaTeX code in RStudio, the code must be produced in the background to make LaTeX able to read it.

Now my question: **Is there any option to let me see the full LaTeX code produced by kable/kableExtra in order to take it and copy it into my pure LaTeX document?**

I would be happy to hear your suggestions.

Best,
Moritz

Comment: Try using the argument `format="latex"` in `kable`, e.g. `knitr::kable(df, format="latex")`

Comment: Thanks @henrik_ibsen! I did that and it works fine when I render the code in RStudio because Rmarkdoan automatically converts the code into Latex. However, I can not see the code, the process runs in the background. My question is how I can see the latex code an take it to copy it into another LaTeX editor.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to get to the `.tex` file from an `.Rmd` file.

1. Convert only to LaTeX by using in your YAML header

   ```
   ---
   [...]
   output: rmarkdown::latex_document
   ---
   ```
2. Convert to PDF but keep the LaTeX file by using in your YAML header

   ```
   ---
   [...]
   output: 
       rmarkdown::pdf_document
           keep_tex: yes
   ---
   ```

I prefer the second approach since it allows for previewing the document easily while editing the `.Rmd` file. Note that there are other output functions besides `rmarkdown::pdf_function` that support the `keep_tex` argument.