# Let knitr/kable display latex code for further editing (.rnw file)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kable

I'm using knitr to compile a .rnw file in a pdf. In the file I use a **kbl()** function to plot a table in RStudio. I'd like to see the LaTeX code produced by kable and kableExtra to realize further editing to the table, but I don't know how to do that. I saw a question about this topic but it was a Rmarkdown document and not a rnw ([Let knitr/kable display latex code for further editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093999/let-knitr-kable-display-latex-code-for-further-editing)).

My question: Is there any option to let me see the full LaTeX code produced by kable/kableExtra in order to take it and copy it into my pure LaTeX document?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://kevinstadler.github.io/notes/knitr-rmarkdown-flavours/) article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run your code with `knitr` in your console. Here is an example:

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

    x  y
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
```

Run this code in your console:

```
knitr::kable(df, format="latex")
```

Output in console:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
x & y\\
\hline
1 & 11\\
\hline
2 & 12\\
\hline
3 & 13\\
\hline
4 & 14\\
\hline
5 & 15\\
\hline
6 & 16\\
\hline
7 & 17\\
\hline
8 & 18\\
\hline
9 & 19\\
\hline
10 & 20\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which gives you the `latex` code so you can copy this and paste in your latex document.