# Let knitr/kable display latex code for further editing (.Rmd file)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

Similar to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093999/let-knitr-kable-display-latex-code-for-further-editing), I have to convert the chunk of code I used to create a kableExtra table from a Rmarkdown file into pure LaTeX format in Overleaf. Unfortunately, I still have not understood how I can get the latex code by running the KableExtra table in the Rmd file.

The following is the YAML header:

```
---
[...]
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
---
```

the following is my code:

```
{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
res_kbl = kableExtra::kbl(merg, longtable=TRUE, booktabs = T, caption = "Table 1", digits = 2) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "HOLD_position"), font_size = 10) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "in Complete sample" = 2, "in Restricted sample" = 2, "MAJ" = 4, "MIN" = 4, "MAJ" = 4, "MIN" = 4)) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "No. of funds" = 4, "Fund Size Complete sample (USD million nominal)" = 8, "Fund Size Restricted sample (USD million nominal)" = 8)) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 5, "Complete sample" = 8, "Restricted sample" = 8)) %>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(row = nrow(merg) - 1, underline = T, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;")
```

My question: How can I get the Latex code for the res_kbl table I have created?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to get the LaTex code of the kable `res_tbl`.

In this case,

1. Specify `format = "latex"` in `kableExtra::kbl()` (or `knitr::kable()`)
2. Next, `writeLines(res_kbl)`

   - Instead, you don't need to assign `res_kbl` variable.
   - You can use additional pipe operator with `writeLines()`.

The result of `writeLines(res_kbl)` will give the code you want. But the code can be complex because `kableExtra` package has so many functionalities.

---

In addition when using only `writeLines()`, you don't need `asis` part in the chunk option. However, `comment` option can be a problem if you want to use it in the final document not in the console. Set the comment as blank text in that chunk.

Comment: Thanks! Was looking exactly for this. The OP should mark this as an accepted answer.